# Who can I safely kill with the Ebony Blade?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to empower the [Ebony Blade](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Blade), and I understand that means I need to kill NPCs that trust me, but I don't want to miss out on any quests or advantages. Several NPCs will become followers, merchants, marriageable, etc. on completion of a quest, and in some cases killing an NPC will affect other NPCs. Which NPCs can I safely kill to empower the Ebony Blade?

This isn't a quest, but I'm trying to get a good two-handed sword and I like this one the best.

Comment: What's the point? Is it a quest?

Comment: You have to kill people to power up the blade, but the trick is they have to be people you have done something for. The general trick people use with this is to pick one person they did something for but generally hate (that mage in whiterun comes to mind) and then kill tha tperson, make them into a thrall, and kill them again over and over until you power the sword up. There is one person you can do this too that is along the north shore and not part of anything, but I can not find his name! So no answer :( Not sure why the downvotes though, this is a valid question IMHO.

Comment: I remember a quest concerning killing a trusted person. If that's the case any mercenary follower will do.

Comment: @james it was closed/down voted due to lack of clarity. If your comment was part of the question, of even just the name of the quest then it would be fine. Although this is still specific to his play through. General advice is good I guess

Comment: This is the second question posted by this user that looks perfectly clear to me, and was closed. IMHO you guys are being a tad too strict at this point. The question could be improved yes, but its certainly not close material, and the user is new to the site. From an outside perspective, this is starting to look like a 'your not one of the cool kids go away' scenario.

Comment: I think this question doesn't have a clear answer. Depending on the users playstyle, the NPCs he can slaughter will differ from other people. For example, maybe he doesn't want to do the brotherood stuff, it'd be safe to assume he can go loco in there. Or if he doesn't like mages, he could go slaughter some up there in the college. It has no clear answer and would therefore not be a "real" question :) It's too subjective.

Comment: The most recent edit is my try. This question is not just totally salvageable, it's actually a pretty good question with a minor amount of re-formatting.

Comment: Yay editing.  That's the kind of question I definitely want to know the answer to.

Comment: as i stand, first time see the post right now, its totally fine and readable. so go editors i guess..

Answer (score 13):

You can use the Dead Thrall spell to repeatedly kill just one NPC who trusts you, instead of having to kill many different ones.

Comment: Delightfully evil and practical. I'll have to try this.

Answer (score 3):

Befriend anyone (such as http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Beitild) who is a Dark Brotherhood assignment. Use Dead Thrall and kill them again and again and again. That way, you complete the Dark Brotherhood Quest and complete the Ebony Blade

See here:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Blade_Victims

Comment: Does the DB bit have any significance?

Comment: @kotekzot - if you wish to complete the dark brotherhood quest line, you have to kill them. and, once you start the quest, the only things you get to say to those people are Dark Brotherhood related. If you destroy the Dark Brotherhood (unrecommended - you lose a lot of fun quests), then there is no significance.

Answer (score 2):

I keep resurrecting Cicero. He is obnoxious and a pleasure to kill.  It charges the ebony blade nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the "In My Time of Need" quest, but didn't kill Kematu at the end, go back to Swindler's Den and kill Kematu and his Alik'r warriors in the room with the waterfall with the Ebony Blade.

Comment: Do his followers also count as friendlies? That would be super sweet.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but they do seem "friendly" when you talk to them. At least they did before I killed them, but I didn't think to use the Ebony Blade on them.

Answer (score 0):

I killed Lydia since she was annoying me, then Jarzargo became my follower and I sort of accidentally killed him when I was swinging at a bunch of Thalmor...dudes...

They have to be your follower, or your spouse ;)

Answer (score 0):

I killed people at Riverwood they give bad quests and most of everyone trusts you there

Answer (score 0):

> Any NPC with a [relationship value [disposition]](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disposition) of 1, 2, or 4
>   [friend, confidant or lover] will power up the blade when slain with
>   it...

- [UESP wiki, on the Ebony Blade](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Blade#Notes)

Here's what I do to power it up, without getting any of the regular named NPCs killed:

I murder* multiple clones of my spouse (through the `player.placeatme <object/base ID>` [console command](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console)) to power up the Ebony Blade. Each time you enter the  `player.placeatme <object/base ID>` console command, you spawn one copy of the NPC whose [object/base ID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Form_ID) you have targeted.

This should work even with non-spouse, killable (non-[essential](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Essential_NPCs)) NPCs, as long as they are a friend, confidant or lover. To know an NPC's [disposition](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disposition) towards you, use the `getrelationshiprank player` (while NPC is targeted) or `player.getrelationshiprank <target NPC refID>` console commands. All spouses are lovers, that's why I'm sure that their clone's deaths will power up the Ebony Blade.

It is best to spawn clones of the person you want to murder in a secluded area where no one else will see you and the clones (to avoid bounties and other NPCs ganging up on you upon witnessing you murdering someone). I prefer doing it in the testing area myself, where no NPC ever goes to. You can go there using the `coc qasmoke` console command. (You can also use the `coc <cellname>` console command to get out of the testing area.)

<sup>* **HAIL SITHIS!** (and Mephala, too)</sup>