# What is the Dead Thrall spell and how do I get it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57105/who-can-i-safely-kill-with-the-ebony-blade) mentions a spell called Dead Thrall ("You can use the Dead Thrall spell to repeatedly kill just one NPC who trusts you").

What exactly does the spell do, and where can I find or buy it?

Comment: How did you find that queston so fast?

Comment: I knew the question you were thinking of and punched in `ebony blade` to the search bar.

Comment: -1 for 0 research effort.

Comment: You don't have to comment just to say that :I

Answer (score 5):

The UESP (Unofficial Elder Scroll Pages) is the most comprehensive repository of information on Elder Scrolls games, Skyrim included. For questions like this, using the UESP's search feature almost always turns up the answer right away.

In this case, it has [an article on Dead Thrall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dead_Thrall), which says in part:

> Dead Thrall is a Master-level Conjuration Spell which raises a dead body permanently to fight for you.

It goes on to say that to obtain the spell you have to have a Conjuration skill of 90 and

> complete the [Conjuration Ritual Spell quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjuration_Ritual_Spell).

Answer (score 3):

The Dead Thrall spell is a master level conjuration spell unlocked after completing the Conjuration Ritual Spell quest. It animates almost any dead humanoid of up to level 40 permanently, i.e. until they die again, to fight for you.

To begin the ritual quest, talk to Phinis Gestor after reaching 90 conjuration. You do not learn the spell directly from this quest but once the quest is completed, you will be able to buy Master level conjuration spells.

Comment: 90 conjuration!! I'll never get that until I'm like a level 50-70!! I don't even have around 30 conjuration on my highest level account (I think he's a level 36 or 37)! Although the only conjuration spells I normally use is Bound Sword, sometimes Bound Battleaxe, and Conjure Flame Atronach.

Answer (score 0):

The spell is the most advanced form of Raise Undead, but it is very hard to obtain and requires a level of 90 in Conjuration. You get it by going to the Wizard Tower in Winterhold and perform a ritual.